# Self Join a Table to Get a Pair of Value But Could Not Receive the Expected Results

Tags: mysql, self-join

I am trying to self join the relation casts(movie_id,cast_id,cast_name). I want to query one pair of actors who have appeared in at least 1 movies together. The self pair must be excluded, and keep the mirror pair.
This is the relation table:

| movie_id | cast_id | cast_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10 | Trung |
| 12340 | 10 | Trung |
| 12341 | 10 | Trung |
| 12342 | 10 | Trung |
| 12343 | 11 | Thi |
| 12340 | 12 | Nhi |
| 12341 | 12 | Nhi |
| 12342 | 12 | Nhi |
| 12343 | 12 | Nhi |
| 12340 | 13 | David |
| 12345 | 12 | Nhi |

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT c.cast_id, c2.cast_id, c.movie_id
FROM casts c, casts c2
WHERE c.cast_id != c2.cast_id AND c.movie_id = c2.movie_id;
```

Instead of getting pairs of different `cast_id`, I got pairs of same `cast_id`.

| cast_id | cast_id | movie_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 12345 |
| 10 | 10 | 12340 |
| 10 | 10 | 12340 |
| 10 | 10 | 12341 |
| 10 | 10 | 12342 |
| 11 | 11 | 12343 |
| 12 | 12 | 12340 |
| 12 | 12 | 12340 |
| 12 | 12 | 12341 |
| 12 | 12 | 12342 |
| 12 | 12 | 12343 |
| 13 | 13 | 12340 |
| 13 | 13 | 12340 |
| 12 | 12 | 12345 |

However, I got different pairs of actors if I try replace one of the attributes to `cast_name` like:

```
SELECT c.cast_name, c2.cast_id, c.movie_id
FROM casts c, casts c2
WHERE c.cast_id != c2.cast_id AND c.movie_id = c2.movie_id;
```

| cast_id | cast_id | movie_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nhi | 10 | 12345 |
| David | 10 | 12340 |
| Nhi | 10 | 12340 |
| Nhi | 10 | 12341 |
| Nhi | 10 | 12342 |
| Nhi | 11 | 12343 |
| David | 12 | 12340 |
| Trung | 12 | 12340 |
| Trung | 12 | 12341 |
| Trung | 12 | 12342 |
| Thi | 12 | 12343 |
| Nhi | 13 | 12340 |
| Trung | 13 | 12340 |
| Trung | 12 | 12345 |

Could you please explain the reason for this behavior and how to fix it to receive the expected results?
Thank you!

Comment: The join is good (but you may want to change that `!=` to `<` so you get every pair once. You need to put all the wanted columns in the SELECT list though:
`SELECT c.movie_id, c.cast_id, c.cast_name, c2.cast_id AS cast_id_2, c2.cast_name AS cast_name_2
FROM casts c, casts c2
WHERE c.cast_id < c2.cast_id AND c.movie_id = c2.movie_id;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thank you for your comment! But what I expect for the result of the query is pairs of entities who are appear in the same movies such as (12,10,12345) where 12 and 10 is the `cast_id` and 1234 is the `movie_id`. But the query that I tried return all the pair of same `cast_id`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Related question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278610/finding-films-where-2-specific-actors-appeared-together-sakila-db/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your issue, I did the the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aa96dcd96ca4b63e6b47917a8b4758a3)):

```
CREATE TABLE actor
(
  movie_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  cast_id  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  cast_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

And populate it (note the pairs as comments - there are 7 pairs):

```
INSERT INTO actor VALUES

(12340, 13, 'David'),  -- David/Nhi, David/Trung, Nhi/Trung - ORDER BY cast_name
(12340, 12, 'Nhi'),
(12340, 10, 'Trung'),

(12341, 12, 'Nhi'),  -- Nhi/Trung
(12341, 10, 'Trung'),


(12342, 12, 'Nhi'),  -- Nhi/Trung
(12342, 10, 'Trung'),

(12343, 12, 'Nhi'),   -- Nhi/Thi
(12343, 11, 'Thi'),

(12345, 12, 'Nhi'),    -- Nhi/Trung
(12345, 10, 'Trung'),

--
--  Three extra records with actors who share a surname - added by me.
--

(12999, 25, 'Nguyen'), -- Nguyen(25)/Nguyen(26) - Nguyen(25)/Nguyen(27) - Nguyen(26)/Nguyen(27)
(12999, 26, 'Nguyen'),
(12999, 27, 'Nguyen');
```

There are 3 possible ways of doing this.

### Method 1 (using `cast_name`):

```
SELECT 
  a1.movie_id, a1.cast_name, a1.cast_id,
  a2.movie_id, a2.cast_name, a2.cast_id
FROM 
  actor a1
JOIN actor a2
  ON  a1.movie_id = a2.movie_id
  AND a1.cast_name < a2.cast_name              -- note cast_name
ORDER BY a1.movie_id, a1.cast_name, a2.cast_name;
```

Result:

```
movie_id    cast_name   cast_id     movie_id    cast_name   cast_id
   12340        David        13        12340          Nhi        12
   12340        David        13        12340        Trung        10
   12340          Nhi        12        12340        Trung        10
   12341          Nhi        12        12341        Trung        10
   12342          Nhi        12        12342        Trung        10
   12343          Nhi        12        12343          Thi        11
   12345          Nhi        12        12345        Trung        10
```

The advantage of this method is that it presents the names in alphabetical order both down (`ORDER BY`) the records **and** across them (`a1.cast_name < a2.cast_name`) if this is desired. The **major disadvantage** is that the 3 duplicate `Nguyen`s have disappeared!

### Method 2 (using `cast_id`):

```
SELECT 
  a1.movie_id, a1.cast_name, a1.cast_id,
  a2.movie_id, a2.cast_name, a2.cast_id
FROM 
  actor a1
JOIN actor a2
  ON  a1.movie_id = a2.movie_id
  AND a1.cast_id < a2.cast_id                    -- note cast_id
ORDER BY a1.movie_id, a1.cast_name, a2.cast_name;
```

Result:

```
movie_id    cast_name   cast_id     movie_id    cast_name   cast_id
   12340          Nhi        12        12340        David        13
   12340        Trung        10        12340        David        13
   12340        Trung        10        12340          Nhi        12
   12341        Trung        10        12341          Nhi        12
   12342        Trung        10        12342          Nhi        12
   12343          Thi        11        12343          Nhi        12
   12345        Trung        10        12345          Nhi        12
   12999       Nguyen        25        12999       Nguyen        26
   12999       Nguyen        25        12999       Nguyen        27
   12999       Nguyen        26        12999       Nguyen        27
```

The advantage here is that we keep the `Nguyen` duplicates, but now the names aren't sorted alphabetically across the record.

### Method 3 (complex):

```
SELECT 
  a1.movie_id, 
  CASE
    WHEN a1.cast_name = a2.cast_name THEN a1.cast_name
    ELSE LEAST(a1.cast_name, a2.cast_name)
  END AS l_name,
  CASE
    WHEN a1.cast_name = a2.cast_name THEN a1.cast_id
    ELSE 
    (
      SELECT a.cast_id FROM actor a 
      WHERE a.cast_name = LEAST(a1.cast_name, a2.cast_name)
      AND   a.movie_id = a1.movie_id
    )
  END AS c1_id,
  a2.movie_id, 
  CASE
    WHEN a1.cast_name = a2.cast_name THEN a2.cast_name
    ELSE GREATEST(a1.cast_name, a2.cast_name)
  END AS g_name,
  CASE
    WHEN a1.cast_name = a2.cast_name THEN a2.cast_id
    ELSE 
    (
      SELECT a.cast_id FROM actor a 
      WHERE a.cast_name = GREATEST(a1.cast_name, a2.cast_name)
      AND   a.movie_id = a1.movie_id
    )
  END AS c2_id
FROM 
  actor a1
JOIN actor a2
  ON  a1.movie_id = a2.movie_id
  AND a1.cast_id < a2.cast_id
ORDER BY a1.movie_id, l_name, g_name;
```

Result:

```
movie_id    l_name  c1_id   movie_id    g_name  c2_id
   12340     David     13      12340       Nhi     12
   12340     David     13      12340     Trung     10
   12340       Nhi     12      12340     Trung     10
   12341       Nhi     12      12341     Trung     10
   12342       Nhi     12      12342     Trung     10
   12343       Nhi     12      12343       Thi     11
   12345       Nhi     12      12345     Trung     10
   12999    Nguyen     25      12999    Nguyen     26
   12999    Nguyen     25      12999    Nguyen     27
   12999    Nguyen     26      12999    Nguyen     27
10 rows
```

Et voilà! Results sorted as per requirements **and** we have the duplicate `Nguyen` You can leave out fields as desired.

This final solution uses the `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions (explained well [here](https://danwatt.org/2019/12/postgresqls-greatest-and-least-function/)) which are two of the most under-utilised functions in the SQL arsenal!

In future, when asking questions like this one, could you please provide a fiddle with your table structure(s) and data.